# Most Active Contributors Monthly Report! - August 2017

Tags: discussion, most-active-contributors, monthly

## Welcome Our SharePoint Stack Exchange Valued Contributors.

We would like to share with you the **Most Active Contributors Report** over the last month!

[image]

**This report includes the following awards:**

1. Monthly Leader Board.
2. Most Active Contributors Award.
3. Most Active Editors Award.
4. Most Active Voters Award.
5. Most Close Votes Review Award.
6. Most First Post Review Award.
7. Most Late Answer Review Award.
8. Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.
9. Most Reopen Review Award.
10. Most Suggested Edit Review Award.
11. Highest Votes Questions Award.
12. Highest Votes Answers Award.
13. Most Viewed Questions Award.
14. 1st Top Contributors summary list.

---

[image]

[image]

You can find the full list at [Stack Exchange Leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/105/month/sharepoint/2017-08-01)

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                   REPUTATION
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                   2,573
2   Priyaranjan KS             1,134
3   Gautam Sheth               965
4   Vishal                     737
5   Aakash Morya               620
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                    EDITS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                   231
2   Aakash Morya               66
3   Aashirya                   35
4   Robert Lindgren            34
5   Gautam Sheth               18
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     VOTES
----------------------------------------------------------
1   Aashirya                   747
2   Well                       351
3   Zsmaster                   280
4   M.Qassas                   239
5   Michelle                   208
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                     35
2   Aakash Morya                 20
3   Gautam Sheth                 17
4   moe                          13
5   Gaurravs                     12
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                     115
2   Aakash Morya                 57
3   hoffie4                      40
4   Gaurravs                     34
5   moe                          19
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                     57
2   Aakash Morya                 11
3   P S                          10
4   Gaurravs                     10
5   hoffie4                      9
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                     74
2   Aakash Morya                 35
3   Gaurravs                     29
4   Gautam Sheth                 28
5   moe                          19
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                     11
2   Aakash Morya                 7
3   Dikesh Gandhi                7
4   Gaurravs                     6
5   Gautam Sheth                 6
```

---

[image]

```
N   WINNER                     REVIEWS
----------------------------------------------------------
1   M.Qassas                     49
2   Trevor Seward                27
3   moe                          18
4   Aakash Morya                 17
5   Ransher Singh                15
```

---

[image]

1. [Creating modern team site takes long time to complete](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224099/creating-modern-team-site-takes-long-time-to-complete)

   - **Quest Owner:** Bernd Rickenberg.
   - **Votes:** 9.
2. [Mentioning someone in a normal discussion board list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224791/mentioning-someone-in-a-normal-discussion-board-list-will-not-show-the-activity)

   - **Quest Owner:** Jhon G.
   - **Votes:** 6.
3. [SharePoint Online - Explorer View asking for selection of certificate](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224762/sharepoint-online-explorer-view-asking-for-selection-of-certificate)

   - **Quest Owner:** Steven D Andrews.
   - **Votes:** 6.

---

[image]

1. [Disable “new document” in document library for specific users](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225077/disable-new-document-in-document-library-for-specific-users/225080#225080)

   - **Answer Owner:** M.Qassas.
   - **Votes:** 8.
2. [SP2013 Event Receiver action open page library\list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225227/sp2013-event-receiver-action-open-page-library-list/225228#225228)

   - **Answer Owner:** M.Qassas.
   - **Votes:** 7.
3. [Are there any risks of doing an Export/Import for a document library between 2 farms, where these 2 farms have different farm build numbers](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/223998/are-there-any-risks-of-doing-an-export-import-for-a-document-library-between-2-f/224253#224253)

   - **Answer Owner:** M.Qassas.
   - **Votes:** 7.

---

[image]

1. [Why is my REST call undefined?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224999/why-is-my-rest-call-undefined)

   - **Views:** 241.
2. [Is it possible to change a field value after a certain number of days?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/223461/is-it-possible-to-change-a-field-value-after-a-certain-number-of-days)

   - **Views:** 240.
3. [Disable “new document” in document library for specific users](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225077/disable-new-document-in-document-library-for-specific-users/225080#225080)

   - **Views:** 206.

---

[image]

1. **Most Active Contributors Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
2. **Most Active Editors Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas)  Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
3. **Most Active Voters Award.**

   - [Aashirya](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/62708/aashirya) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
4. **Most Close Votes Review Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
5. **Most First Post Review Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
6. **Most Late Answer Review Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
7. **Most Low-Quality Posts Review Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas)  Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
8. **Most Reopen Review Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
9. **Most Suggested Edit Review Award.**

   - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Job, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
10. **Highest Votes Questions Award.**

    - [Bernd Rickenberg](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/4285/bernd-rickenberg) Great Question, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
11. **Highest Votes Answers Award.**

    - [M.Qassas](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/53462/m-qassas) Great Answer, Please Keep up your valuable contributions!
12. **Most Viewed Questions Award.**

    - [Why is my REST call undefined?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224999/why-is-my-rest-call-undefined)

---

Please join me in thanking all contributors for volunteering, We fully appreciate all the great contributions of SE members. Please keep your valuable contributing!

> **P.S.:** This report will be published Monthly / Quarterly / Yearly. Please don't hesitate to share your valuable feedback & precious suggestion!

Comment: Congratulations to all winners.... and thanks @M.Qassas for your efforts in contributing to community and generating this reports.